# statsmodels, time series predict out-of-sample error

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

My data:

```
ipdb> dta
             plays
2015-03-01   401.0
2015-03-02   350.0
2015-03-03   448.0
2015-03-04   490.0
...            ...
2015-08-23   655.0
2015-08-24   731.0
2015-08-25   684.0
2015-08-26   774.0
2015-08-27   808.0
2015-08-28   732.0
2015-08-29   694.0
2015-08-30   798.0
```

The data starts from 2015-03-01 to 2015-08-30, and I want to predict the future values.

My code snippt

```
arma_mod30 = sm.tsa.ARMA(dta, (d_level, 0)).fit()
result = arma_mod30.predict('2015-09-01', '2015-10-30', dynamic=True)
```

But the predict fuction returned the fllowing error:

```
ValueError: date 2015-09-01 00:00:00 not in date index. Try giving a date that is in the dates index or use an integer
```

How to predict future dates that not in the date index? Thanks!

Comment: [use ints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210846/statsmodel-predict-start-and-end-indices) or add frequency to the index of dta.

Comment: @dashesy, sir, could you please show more details?

Comment: my guess is that `dynamic=True` requires that the start period is insample. The `forecast` method makes forecasting the next periods easier than `predict`, but is less flexible.